# Not getting required value from json list - flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have this code where am able to get values from an [online json data](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BrightCode1/ohms-json/master/categories.json) and print its value

**main.dart**

```
final String url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BrightCode1/ohms-json/master/categories.json';
  List<JsonModel> myModel = [];
  List<CatSubcategory> subCate = [];
  int localInt;
@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    localInt = 0;
    loadData(localInt);
  }

  loadData(int dataInt) async {
    var res = await http.get(url, headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      String resBody = res.body;
      var jsonDecode = json.decode(resBody);
      for (var data in jsonDecode) {

        data['cat_subcategory'].map((x) {
          return subCate.add(
              CatSubcategory(subName: x['sub_name'], subImage: x['sub_image']));
        }).toList();

        myModel.add(JsonModel(
            category: data['category'],
            catId: data['cat_id'],
            catIcon: data['cat_icon'],
            catSubcategory: subCate));
        setState(() {});
      }

      print(myModel[dataInt].catSubcategory.length);

    } else {
      print("Something went wrong!");
    }

  }
```

**my model.dart**

```
class JsonModel {
  JsonModel({
    this.category,
    this.catId,
    this.catIcon,
    this.catSubcategory,
  });

  String category;
  String catId;
  String catIcon;
  List<CatSubcategory> catSubcategory;

  factory JsonModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => JsonModel(
    category: json["category"],
    catId: json["cat_id"],
    catIcon: json["cat_icon"],
    catSubcategory: List<CatSubcategory>.from(
        json["cat_subcategory"].map((x) => CatSubcategory.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "category": category,
    "cat_id": catId,
    "cat_icon": catIcon,
    "cat_subcategory":
    List<dynamic>.from(catSubcategory.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class CatSubcategory {
  CatSubcategory({
    this.subName,
    this.subImage,
  });

  String subName;
  String subImage;

  factory CatSubcategory.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CatSubcategory(
    subName: json["sub_name"],
    subImage: json["sub_image"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "sub_name": subName,
    "sub_image": subImage,
  };
}
```

The only problem am having now is that when I try to print the length on the subcategory of the first list it gives me `24` instead of `6` and i printed it like this `myModel[dataInt].catSubcategory.length`. The `dataInt` is 0 which means it's supposed to print out the length of the children(`"cat_subcategory"`) with category of `Design & Creativity` but it's printing all the other children of the other lis. So please how do i go about this. And if you need more explanation tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid writing your own model from scratch if you already know the schema of your json.

Just use something like https://app.quicktype.io/ just paste your json and you will get

```
import 'dart:convert';


class Root {
    Root({
        this.category,
        this.catId,
        this.catIcon,
        this.catSubcategory,
    });

    String category;
    String catId;
    String catIcon;
    List<CatSubcategory> catSubcategory;

    factory Root.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Root(
        category: json["category"],
        catId: json["cat_id"],
        catIcon: json["cat_icon"] == null ? null : json["cat_icon"],
        catSubcategory: List<CatSubcategory>.from(json["cat_subcategory"].map((x) => CatSubcategory.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "category": category,
        "cat_id": catId,
        "cat_icon": catIcon == null ? null : catIcon,
        "cat_subcategory": List<dynamic>.from(catSubcategory.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class CatSubcategory {
    CatSubcategory({
        this.subName,
        this.subImage,
    });

    String subName;
    String subImage;

    factory CatSubcategory.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CatSubcategory(
        subName: json["sub_name"],
        subImage: json["sub_image"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "sub_name": subName,
        "sub_image": subImage,
    };
}
```

and then you should be good to just

```
loadData(int dataInt) async {
    var res = await http.get(url, headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
           String resBody = res.body;
           var list = json.decode(resBody) as List;
           List<Root> items = list.map((i)=>Root.fromJson(i)).toList();
           print(items[0].catSubcategory.length);
      }


    } else {
      print("Something went wrong!");
    }

  }
```

https://repl.it/talk/share/Sample/118111